# Please identify cover artist of Flash and the Pan Best Of

Tags: artwork

See here: [Cover/Backcover](https://www.amazon.de/Best-Flash-Pan/dp/B0009SQ6W4)

I could swear I have seen this somewhere...at least the style...maybe Liefeldian? Wild googling didn't get an answer. Maybe it's noted on the backcover, but the pic is too small to read anything. So, do you know the comic artist?

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Hadn't seen a link to "Tour" or I had...You mean, identifying artwork is no-no either? Then close question. Bummer.

Comment: The back cover states it was designed by Mainartery, a cover designer that dissolved in 2008.  I tried to create a Comic Book Stack a few years ago but it never got out of Area 51.  If you're on Facebook, you might try joining one of the comic book pages there and post a pic of the cover and see if anyone recognizes it.

Comment: THX, that helps. Mainartery is also on DeviantArt, which proves no identity, but I could ask him.